# Why can I reassign a const variable in a loop in React js?

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, constants

I am solving a production issue where there was a reassignment of a const that causes an error.[image: console log error in production]

Sorry I couldn't provide a better screenshot, this is what they sent me. So I search for this code & this is what I found:

```
const riskScoringLabel = isaStatus ? (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === riskScoring) || '').label : riskScoringLabel = (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === pendingRiskScoring) || '').label
```

There was reassignment of a const in the 2nd condition, but this was done in a for loop, so on my local & UAT it didn't throw any errors.

```
for (let index = 0; index < applicantISASummaryListing.length; index++) {
            let isaRecord = applicantISASummaryListing[index];

            const { applicantEntityUuid, mainApplicantIdNo, mainApplicantName, jointAccountIdNo1, jointAccountName1, isaStatus, riskScoring, lastCompletedDate, referenceNumber, pendingIsaStatus,
                pendingReferenceNumber, pendingRiskScoring, pendingLastCompletedDate } = isaRecord;

            const riskScoringLabel = isaStatus ? (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === riskScoring) || '').label : riskScoringLabel = (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === pendingRiskScoring) || '').label

/*some other codes here*/

}
```

What I am really confused is why the reassignment of the constant **riskScoringLabel** doesn't throw an error in the for loop, and also why in our UAT and local enviroment it works fine but in production it throws an error.
Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const riskScoringLabel = isaStatus ? (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === riskScoring) || '').label : (riskRatingList.find(item => item.value === pendingRiskScoring) || '').label
```